# Action Mailer - I don't manage to send an automatic email with Action Mailer, GMail and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail, actionmailer

I work on Rails and Action Mailer. I created a form. When the visitors filled the form and sends it, it should trigger the sending of the form, record the form's data in my db, send an automatic email containing the form data to the email of the club chosen by the visitor, then a redirection is set and a flash message shows up to confirm that everything went fine. All is working except the email sending. I am stuck since a few days and can't seem to find why it does not work. I try to send the email through GMail and the account uses the double authentication.
This is my config development code:

```
# Configurations pour l'environnement de développement
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 587,
  domain: 'gmail.com',
  user_name: 'myemail@gmail.com',
  password: 'abcdefghijk',
  authentication: 'plain',
  enable_starttls: true,
  open_timeout: 5,
  read_timeout: 5
}
```

This is my trials_controller:

```
     def create
    @trial = Trial.new(trial_params)
    club_name = params[:trial][:club]
    club = Club.find_by(name: club_name)

    if club
      @trial.club_id = club.id
      if @trial.save
        ClubMailer.rendezvous_email(@trial, club).deliver_now
        flash[:notice] = "Your message was successfully sent!  You will be contacted soon by the club."
        redirect_to root_path
      else
        flash.now[:danger] = "An error occurred. Please try again."
        render :new
      end
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Club not found."
      render :new
    end
  end
```

This is my mailer/club_mailer file:

```
class ClubMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def rendezvous_email(trial, club)
    @trial = trial
    @club = club
    begin
      mail(to: @club.email, subject: "Free trial in #{club.name} club! ")
    rescue => e
      Rails.logger.error "Error sending email: #{e.message}"
      raise e
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What error messages are you receiving?

Comment: Can you please check if `perform_deliveries` is set to false maybe? Or if you have any `config.action_mailer.interceptors` added?

Comment: When you say "the [gmail] account uses the double authentication", do you mean it has 2FA setup? 2 step verification? You can't do that, you need to use what google call an "app password".

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Dbugger, Mike and Smathy for your replies and help. I solved the problem, it came from a credential matter (master key) finally!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).